# how to locate bootstrap.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing off of a template from ThemeForest and I have encountered a styling error. Using the developer tools I can pinpoint that the CSS I'm trying to make changes to are located at http://cdn-main2.myfor.ms/styles/bootstrap.css?51df40cda2

This file is not in my source code nor is being linked to with a link tag in the HTML.
Is there a way to access this file and make changes to it?

[image]

Comment: what you can do is override the styles you want in a new css file. This is a CDN (content delivery network) file hosted on the cloud.

Comment: To build upon what @MehrdadDastgir said as well, if you don't like any of the theming - you can remove the link to this CDN (likely in your `<head>` section of HTML) and remove it altogether. Though it would likely break many parts of your site.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new CSS file to your site and write your own CSS rules, the ones you want to overwrite.

Your stylesheet should be placed after the CDN CSS and should look something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path_to_your_css.css">
```